Why is every 400+ status code triggering onerror?
    function postDto(dto) {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", api_url + "/scores/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200)
                    postresponse = "Commit successful! View score " + "<a href='" + app_url + "/score/" + scoreName + "'>here</a>";
                else
                    postresponse = "Error: " + xhr.status + " - " + xhr.statusText;
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = () => postresponse = "An error occurred.";
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dto));
    }

I needed to make some HTTP requests in this code. I'm writing a plugin for Musescore 4 in QML.
Problem is, any 400+ status code falls on xhr.onerror. Any clue on how to do this right?
Obs.: I had to resort to using XMLHttpRequests because it's the only HTTP library I know that QML works with. CORS is already configured, by the way.

Under what condition would you want an error response in the 400 range to not be counted as an error?

If it's an error I can't see the status code and handle the response appropriately.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I just want to know why my code is catching 400+ status codes as XHR errors instead  of HTTP errors.
